# How Does BIOS Read a Drive?

Tags: bios, bootloader, format

Namely, are all bootloaders the same, so that any BIOS can always read them and pass control to the drive so that FAT32, NTFS, ext4, btrfs, etc. don't need to be understood by the BIOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Pre-GPT, the answer is that the BIOS would check if the disk was bootable (by looking for a specific "magic signature" on the 511th and 512th bytes of the disk), and those bytes were set to the expected value, the BIOS could run the code starting at byte number zero on the disk.

The BIOS does not typically understand the filesystem formats like FAT32 or NTFS or ext4.  The BIOS doesn't even understand partitions.  Being able to recognize partitions is a concept that gets crammed into the bytes of code that get stored at the beginning of the disk.

That boot code will then typically find additional code, which might be another boot loader, or a "second stage boot loader" (OpenBSD does this), which often understands the filesystem a bit more (enough to be able to start locating the kernel, and getting that started).

With GPT ("GUID Partition Table"), the process is a bit more elaborate.  The (U)EFI looks at some other details.  However, there are similarities: The specific details that (U)EFI looks for are not dependent on the filesystem, and the GPT runs code (such as a "boot loader") at that location.